# `raw_execute': unknown command: :mouse_move_to (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to scraping. I am trying to scrape a website using `selenium` . This is the website https://www.ventusky.com/. Each point on the website provides information on mouse over and click. I am trying to perform a simple task of clicking on the website. Here is my code.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://ventusky.com/"
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 50) # seconds
test = driver.find_element(:id,"l")
driver.action.click(test).perform
driver.quit
```

But this throws an error which occurs from the `perform` line of code.

```
/home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:626:in `raw_execute': unknown command: :mouse_move_to (ArgumentError)
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:615:in `execute'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:418:in `mouse_move_to'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:69:in `move_to'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:79:in `move_if_needed'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:33:in `click'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:354:in `block in perform'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:353:in `each'
    from /home/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:353:in `perform'
    from windy.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I do not understand what is going on here.I think it is some problem regards to `ActionBuilder`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `click` method on a found node directly:

```
driver.find_element(:id,"l").click
```

Comment: That solved the issue. Can you tell me how the ``mouse over`` action can be performed?

Comment: @raj I don't know much ruby but it should be something along the lines `driver.move_to_element(driver.find_element(:id,'l'))`

Comment: it is throwing the error i mentioned in this problem.

Comment: @raj you should probably open up a new issue regarding this. I'm not familiar enough with ruby implementation of selenium to help you out here :|